Quarkus OIDC Keycloak provider leads to a blank screen
I recently migrated to Quarkus 3.9.2 on a very small project. Got pretty much everything to work without trouble except for the Quarkus Keycloak Devservice extension.
When I try to authentify through Keycloak Provider as I used to do, I simply obtain a blank screen with no option. I know that the process does not complete normally as I'm not logged in and Swagger UI example requests on my protected endpoints don't work.

Select Keycloak Provider for Authentication

keycloak-provider

Fill in the login form

keycloak-provider-login
keycloak-realm-login-form
URL of the Login form: http://localhost:45180/realms/quarkus/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=quarkus-app&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fq%2Fdev-ui%2Fio.quarkus.quarkus-oidc%2Fkeycloak-provider&scope=openid&response_type=code&response_mode=query&prompt=login&nonce=bZeJhx4&state=pgJp1r6_quarkus_quarkus-app

Get redirected to the blank screen

dev-ui-blank-screen-after-login
Here is my application.properties file that has not been changed during the migration:
%dev.quarkus.keycloak.devservices.users.john=john
%dev.quarkus.keycloak.devservices.roles.john=teacher
%dev.quarkus.keycloak.devservices.users.pascale=pascale
%dev.quarkus.keycloak.devservices.roles.pascale=admin
%dev.quarkus.keycloak.devservices.users.anthony=anthony
%dev.quarkus.keycloak.devservices.roles.anthony=cashier
%dev.quarkus.keycloak.devservices.port=${kc.admin.port.dev:45180}

Some specific details

Users and roles are correctly created in the Realm at the launch of the Keycloak container
Users all have a password correctly assigned in my Realm
I've already tried to use different version of the Keycloak image (quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:YYY) but it didn't change anything.

I'll take any hint, thank you!

Hi, I've opened a bug issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/39876, unfortunately it is a regression. I'll update here once we fix it

My colleague has fixed the issue, expected to work again in 3.9.3, thanks

Thank you for your very fast reaction time!

I confirmed that this was patched with Quarkus 3.9.3. My problem is solved.
